# Characters won't fit in table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, fontsize

I'm using Overleaf to make a uni work and I need to make a table which at first was too long, and now the characters won't fit in the cells.

As I see it's demanded in other posts, I'll paste the whole code here, tho the relevant part is the table one.

I already been looking at other threads but none give me the answer I need! If there's *the one* which will help me, I'll be pleased if you redirect me to it, else if you can help me thank you so much!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{tabu} \usepackage{array}

\title{Informe llarg 1} \author{12dcollgros } \date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

{\centering\section*{Introducció}}

Aquest informe detalla l'experiment realitzat per demostrar les lleis de la dinàmica clàssica, concretament les que descriuen el moviment rectilini uniforme (MRU d'ara en endavant), el moviment rectilini uniformement accelerat (MRUA d'ara en endavant) i la conservació del moment lineal en colisions.

~\\ Per tal de demostrar dites lleis, recrearem al laboratori un entorn semblant al que aquestes lleis fan referència (mínima presència de fregament, velocitats inicials uniformes, etc.) i emprarem mòbils on hi acoblarem distints accessoris per tal de demostrar la llei o equació que escaigui.


 ~\\ {\centering\section*{Experiment 1: Mesura de la velocitat d'un MRU}}

Sabem que la velocitat a la qual es desplaça un mòbil no afectat per forces externes ve donada per:

$$ v = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t} \qquad (1)$$ 

On $\Delta s$ representa l'increment de distància que el mòbil s'ha desplaçat en un increment de temps $\Delta t$. Si dita relació és certa, un mòbil que es mogui a velocitat constant haurà de recòrrer sempre el mateix increment de distància en el mateix increment de temps.


Mitjançant un sistema de quatre portes fotoelèctriques, hem mesurat el temps que un accessori de longitud coneguda ($d = 10 \pm 0.1$ cm) acoblat al mòbil tarda a recòrrer cada porta. D'aquesta manera podem mesurar la seva velocitat a partir de l'equació (1), que si la hipòtesi és certa s'hauria de mantenir constant.

Després de repetir dit experiment 3 vegades, hem obtingut els següents resultats:  ~\\  La incertesa en la mesura dels temps ens ve donada per les pròpies portes i és constant: $\delta t$ = $0.001s$

~\\ Intent 1: \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth { | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X | X |}
        \hline
        Try & t1 & v1 & $\delta v$ & t2 & v2 & $\delta v$ & t3 & v3 & $\delta v$ & t4 & v4 & $\delta v$ \\ \hline
        1 & 0.114 & 0.8764 & 0.016 & 0.112 & 0.89285 & 0.017 & 0.117 & 0.8548 & 0.016 & 0.113 & 0.88502 & 0.017 \\ \hline
        4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        \hline
      \end{tabu} \end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X


\end{document}
```

Comment: As it currently is, your table will only fit into the standard text width of an `article` if you use an extremely small font size. You could therefor a) increase the textwidth globally (with the `geometry` package) b) if your table contains a lot more rows than shwon use a table in landscape mode c) redesign your table to make it narrower (maybe transpose the table).

Comment: There's a lot I'd change. Use an old syntax `$$...$$`; use so many times `//`; the table is not made correctly etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my updated version with a cleaner and more tidy code also for the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\title{Informe llarg 1}
\author{12dcollgros}
\date{April 2019}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
{\centering\section*{Introducció}}

Aquest informe detalla l'experiment realitzat per demostrar les lleis de la dinàmica clàssica, concretament les que descriuen el moviment rectilini uniforme (MRU d'ara en endavant), el moviment rectilini uniformement accelerat (MRUA d'ara en endavant) i la conservació del moment lineal en colisions. Per tal de demostrar dites lleis, recrearem al laboratori un entorn semblant al que aquestes lleis fan referència (mínima presència de fregament, velocitats inicials uniformes, etc.) i emprarem mòbils on hi acoblarem distints accessoris per tal de demostrar la llei o equació que escaigui.


{\centering\section*{Experiment 1: Mesura de la velocitat d'un MRU}}

Sabem que la velocitat a la qual es desplaça un mòbil no afectat per forces externes ve donada per:

\begin{equation}\label{1st}
 v = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}

On $\Delta s$ representa l'increment de distància que el mòbil s'ha desplaçat en un increment de temps $\Delta t$. Si dita relació és certa, un mòbil que es mogui a velocitat constant haurà de recòrrer sempre el mateix increment de distància en el mateix increment de temps. Mitjançant un sistema de quatre portes fotoelèctriques, hem mesurat el temps que un accessori de longitud coneguda ($d = 10 \pm 0.1$ cm) acoblat al mòbil tarda a recòrrer cada porta. D'aquesta manera podem mesurar la seva velocitat a partir de l'equació \eqref{1st}, que si la hipòtesi és certa s'hauria de mantenir constant. Després de repetir dit experiment 3 vegades, hem obtingut els següents resultats:  la incertesa en la mesura dels temps ens ve donada per les pròpies portes i és constant: $\delta t = 0.001$s,

Intent 1: 

   \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |c | c |}
        \hline
        Try & t1 & v1 & $\delta v$ & t2 & v2 & $\delta v$ & t3 & v3 & $\delta v$ & t4 & v4 & $\delta v$ \\ \hline
        1 & 0.114 & 0.8764 & 0.016 & 0.112 & 0.89285 & 0.017 & 0.117 & 0.8548 & 0.016 & 0.113 & 0.88502 & 0.017 \\ \hline
        4 & 5 & 6 & &&&&&&&&&\\ \hline
        7 & 8 & 9 & &&&&&&&&&\\
        \hline
      \end{tabular} 
      \end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X


\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked! Can't check it now tho, how is it that I had to change X's for c's? Any further explanation, may it be in private? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sebastiano: Could you please comment  on why one would still use a `tabu` environment if there are no more `X` type columns? Apart from  that, now the contents fit into the columns but the table nevertheless exceeds the textwidth.

Comment: @leandriis With extreme sincerity I tried with the center `c` to see if it centered the characters. I would use `tabularx` and not `tabu` and I agree with you with the message about the use of `geometry`.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Well, `c` type columns will indeed horizontally center the entries and prevent the entries from being printed over the lines. I agree with you on preferring `tabularx` over `tabu`, however my question stays the same. Why use `tabularx` when there is no `X` type column? In that case, a simple `tabular` environment is sufficient.

Comment: @leandriis You're right. But I'd change the whole user code from the beginning. I wouldn't write like that, because it's all tangled up. It looks like a code taken everywhere in pieces. I always use simple things or a simple tabular or tabularx package.

Comment: @Kingkonig I simply wanted to help you improve your code, which from my point of view contains several material errors. I hope that with humility you can see some changes in both order and syntax.

Comment: @Sebastiano literally my first day using TeX code, trying to learn as much as possible and compenetrate it with university but it is a bit hard tho. I'll note down everything you said, thank you so much!

Comment: @Kingkonig I'll write it down for you with all my heart. Welcome here on this site TeX.SE. and you don't have to thank me for that? I have always helped others and to be available and not selfish. I can direct you to many materials on how to start writing well with LaTeX. I wish you all the best and a happy stay.

Comment: @Sebastiano It doesn't make sense to use `\begin{tabu} to \linewidth` if you don't use `X` columns (I didn't downvote).

Comment: @egreg Estimated and kindest egreg I know who the person is, the same one who made us quarrel two years ago in December 2016 in chat. Believe me with all my heart in your hand if you have time and create a private room I'll tell you some things but in Italian :-(. In English for me it's torture.

Comment: @Sebastiano You don't need to remove the answer, you can improve it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say that your TeX code is terrible.

1. Don't use such things as `~\\` to “leave space between paragraphs. There's no need to.
2. Never leave blank lines before displays
3. Never use `$$`; for numbered equations, use `equation`
4. For cross-references use `\label` and `\eqref` as shown
5. For math oriented documents, load `amsmath`
6. The missing `\usepackage[catalan]{babel}` line might be due to showing a minimal example, but it is necessary also here in order to typeset correctly the document, along with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
7. For numeric tables, use `siunitx`; you also use its features for things such as `$\delta t = \SI{0.001}{s}$` or `$d = \SI{10 \pm 0.1}{cm}$`

The table could be typeset as the contents of a subsection, for instance.

Since you seem to have pretty big tables, a larger line width seems necessary.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\centering} % section titles are centered

\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}

\title{Informe llarg 1}
\author{12dcollgros}
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introducció}

Aquest informe detalla l'experiment realitzat per demostrar 
les lleis de la dinàmica clàssica, concretament les que 
descriuen el moviment rectilini uniforme (MRU d'ara en endavant), 
el moviment rectilini uniformement accelerat (MRUA d'ara en endavant) 
i la conservació del moment lineal en colisions.

Per tal de demostrar dites lleis, recrearem al laboratori un entorn 
semblant al que aquestes lleis fan referència (mínima presència de 
fregament, velocitats inicials uniformes, etc.) i emprarem mòbils 
on hi acoblarem distints accessoris per tal de demostrar la llei 
o equació que escaigui.


\section*{Experiment 1: Mesura de la velocitat d'un MRU}

Sabem que la velocitat a la qual es desplaça un mòbil no afectat per 
forces externes ve donada per:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:speed}
v = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}
On $\Delta s$ representa l'increment de distància que el mòbil s'ha 
desplaçat en un increment de temps $\Delta t$. Si dita relació és 
certa, un mòbil que es mogui a velocitat constant haurà de recòrrer 
sempre el mateix increment de distància en el mateix increment de temps.

Mitjançant un sistema de quatre portes fotoelèctriques, hem mesurat el 
temps que un accessori de longitud coneguda ($d = \SI{10 \pm 0.1}{cm}$) acoblat 
al mòbil tarda a recòrrer cada porta. D'aquesta manera podem mesurar 
la seva velocitat a partir de l'equació~\eqref{eq:speed}, que si la hipòtesi és 
certa s'hauria de mantenir constant.

Després de repetir dit experiment 3 vegades, hem obtingut els següents 
resultats. La incertesa en la mesura dels temps ens ve donada per 
les pròpies portes i és constant: $\delta t = \SI{0.001}{s}$

\subsection*{Intent 1}
\begingroup
%\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % let TeX take care of this
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.5]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.3]
  S[table-format=1.5]
  S[table-format=1.3]
}
\toprule
Try &
  {$t_1$} & {$v_1$} & {$\delta v$} &
  {$t_2$} & {$v_2$} & {$\delta v$} &
  {$t_3$} & {$v_3$} & {$\delta v$} &
  {$t_4$} & {$v_4$} & {$\delta v$} \\
\midrule
1 & 0.114 & 0.8764 & 0.016 & 0.112 & 0.89285 & 0.017 & 0.117 & 0.8548 & 0.016 & 0.113 & 0.88502 & 0.017 \\
4 \\
5 \\
6 \\
7 \\
8 \\
9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- instead of the outdated `tabu` package use a normal `tabular` or `tabularx`
- each row needs to have the same amount of entries seperated by `&` even if they are empty
- `titlesec` package for automatically centred titles
- `parskip` package to have and empty line between paragraphs instead of `~\\`
- use a numbered equation instead of manually adding the equation number
- for a better layout use the `booktabs` package and abandon vertical lines

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

% for nice tables
\usepackage{booktabs}

% centred titles
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\Large\centering}

% space between paragraphs
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\title{Informe llarg 1} 
\author{12dcollgros} 
\date{April 2019}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Introducció}

Aquest informe detalla l'experiment realitzat per demostrar les lleis de la di\-nàmica clàssica, concretament les que descriuen el moviment rectilini uniforme (MRU d'ara en endavant), el moviment rectilini uniformement accelerat (MRUA d'ara en endavant) i la conservació del moment lineal en colisions.

Per tal de demostrar dites lleis, recrearem al laboratori un entorn semblant al que aquestes lleis fan referència (mínima presència de fregament, velocitats inicials uniformes, etc.) i emprarem mòbils on hi acoblarem distints accessoris per tal de demostrar la llei o equació que escaigui.


\section*{Experiment 1: Mesura de la velocitat d'un MRU}

Sabem que la velocitat a la qual es desplaça un mòbil no afectat per forces externes ve donada per:

\begin{equation}
v = \frac{\Delta s}{\Delta t}
\end{equation}

On $\Delta s$ representa l'increment de distància que el mòbil s'ha desplaçat en un increment de temps $\Delta t$. Si dita relació és certa, un mòbil que es mogui a velocitat constant haurà de recòrrer sempre el mateix increment de distància en el mateix increment de temps.


Mitjançant un sistema de quatre portes fotoelèctriques, hem mesurat el temps que un accessori de longitud coneguda ($d = 10 \pm 0.1$ cm) acoblat al mòbil tarda a recòrrer cada porta. D'aquesta manera podem mesurar la seva velocitat a partir de l'equació (1), que si la hipòtesi és certa s'hauria de mantenir constant.

Després de repetir dit experiment 3 vegades, hem obtingut els següents resultats:

La incertesa en la mesura dels temps ens ve donada per les pròpies portes i és constant: $\delta t$ = $0.001s$

Intent 1: 

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *{13}{l} @{}}
        \toprule
        Try & t1 & v1 & $\delta v$ & t2 & v2 & $\delta v$ & t3 & v3 & $\delta v$ & t4 & v4 & $\delta v$ \\ \midrule
        1 & 0.11 & 0.88 & 0.02 & 0.11 & 0.89 & 0.02 & 0.12 & 0.85 & 0.02 & 0.11 & 0.89 & 0.02 \\ 
        4 & 5 & 6 &&&&&&&&&&\\ 
        7 & 8 & 9 &&&&&&&&&&\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill X


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted you :-) thank you very much for another answer.